# Determining deflection of a cylinder

Tags: geometry, 3d

I have a cylinder of length *l* and radius *r* and I am trying to work out how far off straight it is. (What I mean by that is assuming the other end of the cylinder is at 0,0 what is the deflection from end to end. Does that make sense? I'm sorry I'm having trouble finding a good word to explain it. I hope it is clear otherwise ask in the comments.)

I can get the x, y (and maybe z, if it's possible to solve without the z then please explain how to do it that way) of 5 points from the circumference of the cylinder. How would I work out how straight it is from this information?

I'm thinking that it may be solvable by determining the ellipse created by the angle and then working out the angle by knowing that it should be a circle. Is that right? how would I do this?

Thanks a lot!

---

Some clarification on what I mean:

[This](https://imgur.com/tpzZBZq) is the setup, Imagine the x axis going into and out of the screen, the y axis going up and down and the z axis going left and right. Now assuming it was directly along the z axis (ie straight) when we looked along the z axis we would see a [circle like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJesP.png). However if it was not directly along the z axis, say the end was slightly (a lot in the example picture) higher in the y axis [we would see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HByv0.png). This is still viewing it directly along the z axis, it's just the cylinder no longer goes directly along the z axis. The shape at the end is no longer a circle when viewed like this, as you can see. If we had x,y coordinates of several points (I can get as many as needed, fewer is best, but accuracy is key) on that ellipse's circumference, could we determine the elevation along the x and y axis as compared to straight along the z axis? How would we determine it if we had the x, y and z coordinates?

Comment: So I'm imagining the cylinder going upwards on the z axis with the base centered at (0,0) on the x,y axis. is that correct?

Comment: So I'm imagining the cylinder going upwards on the z axis with the base centered at (0,0) on the x,y axis. is that correct? If that is correct then you would need the z coordinates as well because a change of 1 inch is a 45 degree angle when z is 1 inch high but a different angle when z is larger. Also, why do you need x and y? is the cylinder deforming its shape? I don't get it at all. why not just follow the side of the cylinder?

Comment: @MadScientist imagine like a straw being held by a clamp or whatever, that would be your 0. now the length of the straw would be approximately your z axis as it doesn't quite go exactly along the z axis but is deflected partially. So if we were to look along the z axis we would not see a true circle because of this deflection, we would see an ellipse right? now if we got several x,y coordinates of this ellipse, knowing that it should be a circle and knowing the length of the end of the straw to the base clamp we should be able to work out the angle of deflection right? Is that clearer now?

Comment: Also we know the radius of the circle

Comment: @Aequitas I think you're assuming that the curvature is constant. If the curvature varies, then anything could happen. But if the curvature is constant then eventually the cylinder would come back around, but it wouldn't be an ellipse, it would be a circle. then you don't need 5 points. if you have two points on a circle then you can calculate the distance between them and apply trig to get the angle

Comment: @Aequitas I think this is what you want: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature_(mathematics) I guess it could be an ellipse but I don't see why, given your description, it would necessarily be an ellipse. it depends on what your points are.

Comment: @Aequitas if the ellipse is huge or the points are very close together so the deflection is small then there won't be a measurable difference between the ellipse and the circle.

Comment: @MadScientist hey i've made some images to better explain what I mean.